# Why wont DirectSound Buffer play under debug conditions?

Tags: c#, debugging, audio, directsound

My wave won't play under debug. If I hit CTRL+F5 I get a nice WAV and the Console writes out the file cursor position (`buf.PlayPosition`) and then the method exits when the sound is over. Under debug (when I just hit F5) there is no audio output, however the file cursor position is still increased in the console window and the method exits without exception.

```
using Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound;

public void Play()
    {
        var fileName = "bass.wav";
        using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {       
            using (var dev = new Device())
            {
                dev.SetCooperativeLevel(this, CooperativeLevel.Priority);
                using (Buffer buf = new Buffer(stream, dev))
                {
                    buf.Volume = 0;
                    buf.Play(0, BufferPlayFlags.Default);
                    while (buf.Status.Playing)
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine("playing " + buf.PlayPosition);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled the Visual Studio Hosting Process and this seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you need to give the buffer "Global Focus" using the BufferDescription.   From the C++ Docs:

> "The DSBCAPS_GLOBALFOCUS flag in the
>   example ensures that the buffer will
>   continue playing even when the
>   application window is not in the
>   foreground. Without this flag, the
>   buffer will be muted when another
>   application or even a dialog box has
>   the input focus."

Try using the [public SecondaryBuffer(Stream, BufferDescription, Device);](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms812405.aspx)  form of the constructor.

Comment: What's the benefit of using a SecondaryBuffer over using a Buffer?