# Does playing a Program from VS2005 cause a program to work any different than the .exe file?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2005

There is a program where I work that works fine when running the .exe file but works differently from expected when opened in VS2005 and played from there. I am therefore asking on here if anyone knows of anything that would work in the .exe file but not the debug from VS? I am not able to post the code for the buttons I'm talking about but I'll try to explain the best I can.

There is a receiver hooked up to the computer. When the button is pressed on the program, it shows a message and waits for a signal to be received. After the signal is heard the first message box is supposed to close and another is supposed to open. When using the .exe file this happens just fine. However when playing from the program from VS2005 (the same one from which the .exe was made) the second message doesn't come up when it is supposed to and when I can make it come up, the first box doesn't close. There is also a timer involved if that helps.

Also, is there a fundamental difference between how the two operate when executing the program?

If I need to make anything more clear or give more details please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running a program under the supervision of a debugger can change the timing of events compared to running the program standalone.  The debugger slows things down.  Normally, this doesn't make any difference to the operation of the program, but if you have code that is dependent on the "coincidental" rapid timing of some activity, that happy coincidence may be broken when things slow down under debugger control.

The debugger can also cause changes in focus and activation depending on where you set your breakpoints - generally not a good idea to set a breakpoint in focus change or activation events because stopping at the breakpoint will change focus to the debugger, away from your app.  But these are interaction issues.  Just running your program under the debugger with no breakpoints shouldn't affect focus or activation in your app.

Review your code carefully.  Consider what could happen to your program flow if you inserted delays between every source code statement.  If that could lead to problems, you have a design bug that needs to be fixed.  Reliance on coincidental timings will lead to bug reports and support calls, particularly if your customers have slower hardware than your development machine.

Comment: This is just what I was going to say.

Comment: Thank you!  I've spent a lot of time in the debugger chasing "Heisenberg" effects.  ;>

Answer (score 1):

When you run under the debugger, or even in the VS testing host, there are some subtle differences.  This shouldn't effect your program under normal circumstances, however, since most of the differences are similar to running (the debug version) of your application on a slower system.

Given your descriptions, I suspect that your problem is actually due to calling to the UI from a different thread than the control was constructed with.  Make sure to always marshal any calls to the UI using Control.Invoke or Control.BeginInvoke.

Answer (score 0):

It may be an issue with the Host Process, disabling it is a painless click and just as easy to re-enable. It may be worth giving a try.

[Disable Host Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185330(VS.80).aspx)

[I know this can effect Direct X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135342/why-wont-directsound-buffer-play-under-debug-conditions) and other API but I've never had exactly the situation you are in so I make no promise.